# plot mollifier of a function in mathematica

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, approximation, convolution

My goal is the compute and plot the mollifier of a function $f(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/4}\chi_{(-1,1)}.$ Given an approximation of the identity $\rho$, the mollifier is defined as
$$f_\epsilon(x)=\int \rho_\epsilon(x-y)f(y)dy$$
where $\rho_\epsilon =\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rho(x/\epsilon)$. The function $\rho=C \exp(-1/(x^2-1))\chi_{(-1,1)}$ and $0$ outside the unit ball. The constant $C$ is chosen such that $\int \rho =1.$

Choosing the value $\epsilon=0.5$ here is the code that I wrote to compute and plot this function,

```
F[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, Abs[x] >= 1}, {(1 - x^2)^(-1/4), Abs[x] < 1}}];

G[x_] := 
Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], Abs[x] < 1}, {0, Abs[x] >= 1}}];
c := Integrate[G[x], x];
R[x_] := (1/c) G[x];
\[Epsilon] := 0.5;
ScaleR[x_] := (1/\[Epsilon]) R[x/\[Epsilon]];

ApproxF[y_] := Convolve[F[x], ScaleR[x], x, y];

Plot[ApproxF[y], {y, -10, 10}]
```

When I run the above code on Mathematica, the code just keeps running and I see no output. Is there something I can do to speed up the computations?

Comment: When I evaluate ApproxF[0], I get a complicated expression with some piecewise functions and indefinite integrals all depending on a formal argument x. I wouldn't expect that to be plottable at all. It looks like sometimes you're expecting arguments to your functions F & G to be formal variables (like literally x) and sometimes values, so it's not clear to me why you're defining them with SetDelayed. And you certainly don't need SetDelayed for epsilon. I don't know the math well enough to make suggestions, but I think you're probably not using Mathematica semantics correctly.

Comment: $\rho=C \exp(-1/(1-x^2))\chi_{(-1,1)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- According to the definition of `mollifier`. we define

```
c = 1/NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], {x, -1, 1}];
ρ[ϵ_][x_] = (c/ϵ)*
   Piecewise[{{Exp[-ϵ^2/(ϵ^2 - x^2)], -ϵ < 
       x < ϵ}}];
```

and plot the `mollifier` $\rho_{\epsilon}|_{\epsilon= 1}=\rho_{1}=\rho$.

```
Plot[ρ[1][x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

- In the convolve,we use `NIntegrate` instead of `Convolve` to faster the plot.

```
Clear[f, f1,f2, c, ρ, ϵ];
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{0, Abs[x] >= 1}, {(1 - x^2)^(-1/4), Abs[x] < 1}}];
c = 1/NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], {x, -1, 1}];
ρ[ϵ_][x_] = (c/ϵ)*
   Piecewise[{{Exp[-ϵ^2/(ϵ^2 - x^2)], -ϵ < 
       x < ϵ}}];
f1[ϵ_][x_] := 
 NIntegrate[ρ[ϵ][x - t]*
   f[t], {t, -∞, ∞}]
f2[ϵ_][x_] := 
 NIntegrate[ρ[ϵ][t]*
   f[x - t], {t, -ϵ, ϵ}]
ϵ = .1;
Plot[{f[x], f1[ϵ][x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
Plot[{f[x], f2[ϵ][x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very smart approach to change the `Convolve` like so!!!